# Create Rounded Corners in Line Chart [vue-chart.js]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts

I render a Line Chart, How can I make it have bottom border radius? I have the Line Chart inside a Card, and the Card has `border-radius` of `6px` no `padding-bottom` so the line chart sticks at the bottom and I want the Chart to have `border-radius` of `6px`, How can I do that?

```
import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
  const { reactiveProp } = mixins

  export default {
    extends: Line,
    mixins: [reactiveProp],
    data: () => ({
      options: {
        layout: {
          padding: {
            bottom: -20,
            left: -20,
          }
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              min: 0,
              display: false,
            },
            gridLines: {
              drawBorder: false,
              showBorder: false,
              display: false,
            },
          }],
          xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
              drawBorder: false,
              showBorder: false,
              display: false,
            },
            ticks: {
              display: false
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    }),
    mounted () {
      // this.chartData is created in the mixin.
      // If you want to pass options please create a local options object.
      this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: do you have a working example / jsfiddle you can share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `overflow: hidden;` on your card class.
Or, you can target the rendered chart canvas itself and set the border radius on it like `.card #line-chart { border-radius: 6px; }`

Examples: https://codepen.io/mix3d/pen/JjoRKGa